# Problem with flutter_facebook_login in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, facebook-authentication

I am working on Flutter application using facebook authentication. As per the first step I added `flutter_facebook_login: ^2.0.1` in `pubspec.yaml`. And I tried to run in debug mode. I get the following error:

```
    Error connecting to the service protocol: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://127.0.0.1:51195/1vmwn2gEVK8=/ws
```

Comment: Which version of Android are you using?

Comment: Physical device with Android Loplipop 5.1 or API level 21-22. Is this the right answer or you mean something else?

Comment: did you solve the problem? @leo-boy

Answer (score 3):

I have solve this problem by following this steps.

Once you have the Facebook App ID figured out, youll have to do two things.

First, copy-paste the following to your strings resource file. If you don't have one, just create it.

**\/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Your App Name here.</string>

    <!-- Replace "000000000000" with your Facebook App ID here. -->
    <string name="facebook_app_id">000000000000</string>

    <!--
      Replace "000000000000" with your Facebook App ID here.
      **NOTE**: The scheme needs to start with `fb` and then your ID.
    -->
    <string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fb000000000000</string>
</resources>
```

Then you'll just have to copy-paste the following to your *Android Manifest*:

**\/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />

<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: remember to do a gradle sync